# Discord PY Using Lambda with channel.history().find(), possible? Trying to find latest message by all users (activity check)

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to use this snippet of code I found to check for last time a user messaged on any channel in the Discord server. The source I found is to for oldest message but looks to do what I need - but I get an error on channel.history().find. The error is:

```
AtrributeError: async_generator object has no attribute "find"
```

Can .find not be used with channel.history or am I using this wrong?

```
#for a given user, check channel history for posts made by that user. 

@bot.command()
async def lastMessage(ctx):

users_id = ctx.author.id
oldestMessage = None
for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels
    fetchMessage = await channel.history().find(lambda m: m.author.id == users_id)
    if fetchMessage is None:
        continue


    if oldestMessage is None:
        oldestMessage = fetchMessage
    else:
        if fetchMessage.created_at > oldestMessage.created_at:
            oldestMessage = fetchMessage

if (oldestMessage is not None):
    await ctx.send(f"Oldest message is {oldestMessage.content}")
else:
    await ctx.send("No message found.")
```

Then I did it by just looping through the messages. It will take a huge amount of time (like 24 hours) though. I guess I can save a little time by looping on messages backwards, and maybe saving all the messages to a list instead of re-fetching in the loops.. Is there a better/faster way to do this with lambda?

```
    for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels:
        
        fetchMessage = None

        async for message in ctx.channel.history(limit=2000):
           
            if message.author == member:
                fetchMessage = message

                if newestMessage is None:
                    newestMessage = fetchMessage
                else:
                    if fetchMessage.created_at < newestMessage.created_at:
                        newestMessage = fetchMessage



     print(newestMessage)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The find you were trying to use is `discord.utils.find` alternatively (maybe faster is get):

```
msg = await discord.utils.get(channel.history(), author__name='Dave')
```

While the other answer should be much slower - think about the dict idea which will be faster than any realtime lookup method, but with high initial cost.

Answer (score 1):

the fetched history is in order. So if you find the first occurance you found is the latest occurance in that channel and you can go on to the next.
Secondly you could specify an after command e.g. 6 months to prevent the script to crawl all the way back to the channel start.

```py
      newestMessage = None
      for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels: # theoretically you could parallise these too
            async for message in ctx.channel.history(limit=2000, after=...):
           
                if message.author == member:
                    if newestMessage is None:
                        newestMessage = message
                    else:
                        if message.created_at < newestMessage.created_at:
                            newestMessage = message
                    break # User was found no need to continue looking in this channel
 
      if newest Message is None:
          # user never talked
      else:
          # was found
```

---

Further you could also **do this once for all users and store them in a dictionary**, csv file etc. and run it every week or so and you would have a lookup that just takes a few seconds at worst.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I may make some kind of db or something so I can do more with this info, but this also isn't really going to be used as a command rather run once in a while to generate some spreadsheets. Appreciate the info though!